# Unable to convert pandas str column with .0 to int

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this...

```
xdf = pd.DataFrame({ 'foo': ['1', '2', '3']})
```

| foo |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

And I want to convert the column to type `int`. I can do that easily with...

```
df = df.astype({ 'foo': 'int' })
```

But if my dataframe looks like this...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'foo': ['1.0', '2.0', '3.0']})
```

| foo |
| --- |
| 1.0 |
| 2.0 |
| 3.0 |

And I try to convert it from `object` to `int` then I get this error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.0'
```

Why doesn't this work? How would I go about converting this to an `int` properly?

Comment: That's how the `int()` function works. You can't convert a string with decimals into an integer directly. Convert it to `float` first, then to `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a two step conversion, string to float then float to int.

```
>>> df.astype({ 'foo': 'float' }).astype({ 'foo': 'int' })
   foo
0    1
1    2
2    3
```

It works with or without the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the downcast option of to_numeric method.

`df['foo'] = pd.to_numeric(df['foo'], downcast='integer')`